# Pop up Window using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11

The Following code is working fine in firefox. But when it comes to IE 11 I am getting popup window when I close the popup the screen color should change to white but the screen color is not changing to white.
If I click on the page after closing the popup. it becoming white.

```js
var popupWindow = null;

function child_open() {
  popupWindow = window.open("popUp.html", "mywindow", "resizable='yes';scrollbars=yes,toolbar=no,menubar=no,status=no,width=700,height=350");
  document.body.style.backgroundColor = "lightgray"
  document.body.display = 'block';
}

function parent_disable() {
  if (popupWindow && !popupWindow.closed) {
    popupWindow.focus();
  } 
  else {
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = "white";
  }

}
```

```html
<html>

<head>


</head>

<body onFocus="parent_disable();" onclick="parent_disable();" onload="child_open();">

</body>

</html>
```

What will be the problem.

Answer (score 1):

This seems like an issue with IE not focusing the parent back. So the code never runs. Can you try manually focusing the parent body?

```
window.focus();
```